# mega.py Can I open browser?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to create a script that allows me to manage multiple mega accounts. What I would like to do is that the script logs me in automatically and it opens my cloud drive in firefox. Is it possible? I succeeded only in logging in with mega.py, but I don't know how to open the browser in my cloud drive.
Here's my code:

```
import mega
from mega import Mega
def login():
    # user details
    email = "Email"
    password = "Password"

    mega = Mega()

    m = mega.login(email, password)

login()
```

Comment: You can use `subprocess` for that, what operating system are you using?

Comment: something like `subprocess.check_output(["firefox","--new-window","https://mega.nz/<rest of yourlink>"]`

Comment: @BijayRegmi Thanks for answering. I use archlinux. I'm new to python, so I don't know how to achieve what I would like to do